# printf() is only printing null values during my while loop

Tags: c, printf

Can anyone explain why I get a readout of: (null) (null) (null) when trying to print the value of a string?

Here is my code:

```
char
translate(char *fileName2)
    {
   char *str1;
   int counted;
   int count;
   int printed;
   int i;
   FILE * fp;
   i = 0;
   count = 0;
   counted = 0;
   printed = 0;
   fp = fopen(fileName2, "r");
   do
    {
       if (!feof(fp)&&counted==0)
         {
              count+=1;
              readToken(fp);
         }
      else
         {
             counted=1;
         } 
    }
    while (counted==0);
     printf("there are %d words in the file %s\n",count,fileName2);
     do 
     {
    if (i<count)
         {
            //Problem here
            printed=0;
            i+=1;
            str1 = readToken(fp); 
            printf("%s ",str1); //THIS IS WHERE THE NULL GETS PRINTED!!
            //free(str1);
         }
      else
         {
            printed=1;
            printf("file has been printed\n");
            printf("value of count here is:%d\n",count);
            printf("value of i here is:%d\n",i);
         } 
      }
     while(counted==1&&printed==0);
   fclose(fp);
   return(0);
    }
```

I just really don't understand why it's giving me (null) for the value of str1 when I try to print it. There's probably a better way to do this, but I'm not the most advanced so any suggestions would be appreciated...Thanks :)

EDIT:
Here is the code for readToken()

```
char *
readToken(FILE *fp)
{
int ch,index;
char *buffer;
int size = 80;

skipWhiteSpace(fp);

ch = fgetc(fp);
if (ch == EOF) return 0;

buffer = allocateMsg(size,"readToken");

index = 0;
while (!isspace(ch))
    {
    if (ch == EOF) break;
    if (index > size - 2)
        {
        ++size;
        buffer = reallocateMsg(buffer,size,"readToken");
        }
    buffer[index] = ch;
    ++index;
    ch = fgetc(fp);
    }

/* push back the character that got us out of this loop */

ungetc(ch,fp);
buffer[index] = '\0';

return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Well, you haven't shown `readToken`, but presumably it is returning `NULL`. If you want to ask a question about that, you'd need to show the code of `readToken` and the contents of the file you're reading.

Comment: Oh you're right. I didn't even think of that since it worked fine returning strings elsewhere in my program but I'll check that out. It functions basically the same as a fscanf() though.

Comment: Please take some time to learn how to use a debugger, step through lines of code, examine variables, etc.  It will save you a lot of time.  SO is not a replacement for that.

Comment: Even with @Dere0405 good fix, code will still have trouble if `fopen()` fails.  suggest checking `fp = fopen(fileName2, "r"); if (fp == NULL) Handle_OpenFailure();`.

Comment: @chux yes, that is definitely a good check to run which I have not yet added. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to add

```
  rewind(fp);   //you need to reset the file pointer to the beginning.
```

before your second while loop:

```
     do 
    {
      if (i<count)
      {
        //Problem here
        printed=0;
        i+=1;
        str1 = readToken(fp); 
        printf("%s ",str1); //THIS IS WHERE THE NULL GETS PRINTED!!
        //free(str1);
      }
      else
      {
        printed=1;
        printf("file has been printed\n");
        printf("value of count here is:%d\n",count);
        printf("value of i here is:%d\n",i);
      } 
   }
   while(counted==1&&printed==0);
```